# Thumbnail MKMapView without Google Logo

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I am in the process of developing a thumbnail MKMapView to show a singular point on the map. However, as the thumbnail is only 70x61px, the google logo takes up a large proportion of the map.

Please can you tell me a way of using the MKMapView so that the google logo is less visible or can't been seen, but avoiding app rejection, or any alternatives to using the MKMapView?

Thanks in advanced.

How it looks at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Review guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html I'm not sure there's any as good alternative at the moment other than contacting Google to get the personal documented permission.

Comment: Agree with A-Live Apple will reject the app if you use GMaps and don't show their logo. A good option is to use Apple's maps (available from iOS 6)

Comment: What about iOS versions lower than iOS 6 as I am targeting 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looking into the Google Maps Static API? It returns regular jpeg maps rather than interactive ones. You might be able to craft a URL that gets you a small enough image for your thumbnail. I don't know whether that would be ok according to their license or not.

Answer (score 0):

Start developing with the iOS 6 beta.  There are significant changes to MapKit that removes Google as the data provider (and thus their logo).  The final version of iOS 6 and it's SDK will be released in the next couple of weeks.  So you will also be good to go submitting an iOS 6 app soon.

Comment: The App will be for iOS 6 and below, so the same APIs are not available. Also, you have just gone against the Apple NDA. You are not allowed to post information regarding pre-release software updates or betas.

Comment: It would have been against the NDA if he posted some code. Everyone knows that iOS 6 has changes to MapKit. It was announced in the WWDC and has been posted at many places.